# PHP Page Stopped outputting content After Running "yum install php-devel" Command

Tags: linux, php, yum

This error is bizarre but after running the "yum install php-devel" command (after a long day of trying to install Facedetect and OpenCV for face detection) my site stopped functioning. The site uses mysql and php. When you hit the url, the page executes the mysql and the php, but it appears to randomly stop outputting the content of the page.

None of the code was changed and the site was working flawlessly prior to running the mentioned ssh command.

I do use output buffering in the site, but after removing the calls "ob_flush", "ob_end_flush" and "ob_start" it didn't appear to help—still having issues with the site.

**Any ideas what this could be?**

Here is output from terminal:

```
[myserver ~]# cd Facedetect-4b1dfe1

[myserver Facedetect-4b1dfe1]# phpize
    Configuring for:
    PHP Api Version:         20090626
    Zend Module Api No:      20090626
    Zend Extension Api No:   220090626

[myserver Facedetect-4b1dfe1]# configure
bash: configure: command not found

[myserver Facedetect-4b1dfe1]# phpize && configure && make && make install 
    Configuring for:
    PHP Api Version:         20090626
    Zend Module Api No:      20090626
    Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
 bash: configure: command not found
bash: Read: command not found

[myserver Facedetect-4b1dfe1]# make
    make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

[myserver Facedetect-4b1dfe1]# yum install php5-devel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configure script isn't in a directory that is part of your shell path, so it's not executing, which is throwing an error (bash: configure: command not found). Instead of

```
configure
```

it should be

```
./configure
```

so

```
phpize && ./configure && make && make install
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-script-name-to-run-it-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide OS versions nor how do you know that mysql and php executes nor whether there are any messages in the Apache error log -- despite all these problems, I would guess because of 'yum' that you are running CentOS or Redhat Enterprise. Now, these are notorious for shipping old, old PHP versions that people replace with newer ones but yum might've installed the OS version. Say, if it's CentOS / RHEL 5 then you now have PHP 5.1... while previously you had 5.3. Of course if you are on RHEL 6 then this doesn't apply. In that case you need to provide us with errors.